# sqrt function in R issue

Tags: r

I am calculating the `mse` and `mae` for my least square fit model in `R`.

```
library(boot)
k = 10
set.seed(1)

mse.ls = rep(0,times =k)
mae.ls = rep(0,times =k)
mse.lad = rep(0,times =k)
mae.lad = rep(0,times =k)
predict.ls = rep(0,times = 20)
predict.lad = rep(0,times = 20)
folds = sample(1:k,nrow(Mydata), replace = TRUE)
for(j in 1:k){
ls.fit = lm(HtVol~ Ht+Wt+Ht*Wt, data=Mydata[folds!=j,])
pred.ls = predict(ls.fit,Mydata[folds==j,])
mse.ls[j] = sqrt(mean((Mydata$HtVol[folds==j]-pred.ls)^2)) 
mae.ls[j]=mean(abs(Mydata$HtVol[folds==j]-pred.ls))
predict.ls[folds==j]=pred.ls
}
```

When I execute,

```
mse.ls[j] = sqrt(mean((Mydata$HtVol[folds==j]-pred.ls)^2))
```

the output has a `sqrt` in only the last value of the vector:

```
mse.ls
[1]  1671.18130  3098.68369  9211.37483  9263.10585  1176.78916 
22022.38220  8581.95307  8209.25681  5868.43977
[10]    76.07184
```

If I take a `sqrt` separately, then it works for the whole vector,

```
sqrt(mse.ls)
[1]  40.88008  55.66582  95.97591  96.24503  34.30436 148.39940  
92.63883  90.60495  76.60574  76.07184
```

Can someone tell me what am I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is your closing `}`?

Comment: Also, you can declare the initial vectors like mse.ls, mae.ls etc as `mse.ls = numeric(k)`.

Comment: @HongOoi I have a lot of trailing code beneath so i skipped the other part.
I have the closing `}`

Comment: The reason is for you to obtain a vector, you have to save it in a matrix/list. You cannot save a vector inside a vector.

Comment: I do not see any reason for the behaviour you mention - likely the problem is something else. Try to do this with something like the `iris` data, and see if the problem persists.